# js Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

This problem involves some js that works on one website and does not work on another. Exact same code.

The purpose of this code is to cause top navigation to be replaced by a fa fa-bars Menu when on a mobile device (or when browser window size is reduced).

It works on www.motorsport-tech.com. However, it generates an "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined" on www.skyforestinn.com.

I place this script immediately before the close body tag:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
            x.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
            x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
    }

    // When user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>
```

and I call it in the html via:

onclick="myFunction()"

Pretty new to javascript and reading about 20 responses to this same problem did not help, as the code works on one website and not the other. Very confusing. Can someone PLEASE tell me what I am doing wrong (aside from not knowing what I'm doing in the first place) or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

This is your script, taken verbatim from the site:

```
// Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button        function myFunction() {         var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");         if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {             x.className += " w3-show";          } else {                x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");          }       }       // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it     var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');     window.onclick = function(event) {        if (event.target == modal) {          modal.style.display = "none";         }     }
```

It is one line which starts with a comment, so it does absolutely nothing.

Format it properly instead, and it should work as expected:

```
<script>
// Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it 
var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, I'd suggest putting the script in a separate file if possible, allowing you to separate the HTML from the JS, and making editing easier, eg

```
<script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
```

Then when you open `myscript.js`, problems like these will be easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

One site has an optimization that removes all line breaks, that means any single line comment will comment out all of the following code

If you want to fix it without tracking down the setting removing line breaks, use a multiline comment `/* */` instead

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
            x.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
            x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
    }

    /* When user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it */
    var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Jesus... You nailed it. I changed to multiline comments and that fixed it. No wonder it couldn't find the function. Thank you SO much...